# Printing bitfields and instructions in c

Tags: c

I have the following exercise. I have to code the different types of instruction types and print them. I have to print with testPrint a instruction in the correct order. The function create_rtype_hex creates an r-type in a binary representation. One could simply print this with a little effort. The problem now is that I have to convert the binary into (union Instrution) and then print it. I have no idea how to even access this somehow. It may be that the strucutres that I've created are wrong. But the foundation is given by the exercise. Any hints?

Given are the following functions:

```
//main command
testPrint(create_rtype_hex(FC_ADD, 0x0000, I_T0, I_T1, I_T2, OC_ADD))

void printInstruction(union Instruction *i) {
//create this function
}

void testPrint(word w) {
    union Instruction*  instruction = (union Instruction *) &w;
    printInstruction(instruction);
}

typedef struct {
    struct  InstructionTypeI0 {
        unsigned long immediate: 15;
        unsigned char rt:4; // start a new byte
        unsigned char rs : 6;
        unsigned char opcode : 2;
    } reg1;
} InstructionTypeI_t;



typedef struct {
    struct  InstructionTypeJ0 {
        unsigned long address: 25;
        unsigned char opcodce: 5;
    } reg2;
} InstructionTypeJ_t;

typedef struct {
    struct  InstructionTypeR0 {
        unsigned long funct: 15;
        unsigned char shamt:4; // start a new byte
        unsigned char rd : 6;
        unsigned char rt : 2;
        unsigned char rs: 4;
        unsigned char opcode: 5;
    } reg3;
} InstructionTypeR_t;


/* TODO Task (d) add union Instruction here */
typedef union Instruction{
    InstructionTypeI_t i;
    InstructionTypeJ_t j;
    InstructionTypeR_t r;
}Instruction;


word create_rtype_hex(unsigned short funct, unsigned short shamt, unsigned short rd, unsigned short rt, unsigned short rs, unsigned short opcode) {
    return funct + (shamt << 6) + (rd << 11) + (rt << 16) + (rs <<21) + (opcode << 26);
}
```

Comment: OT: The number of bits for the different instruction types are not equal. How do you differentiate the instruction types if you have only their binary representation?

Comment: I added create_rtype_hex(). This is a great question that I also asked myself how do I differentiate them.

Comment: @thebusybee Please do no name specific things which are missing from shown code. Instead refer to [mre]. (type `[mre]` for convenience)

Comment: The differentiation would be possible without known the length in advance if a corresponding encoding is used. I.e. the already know bits tell you whether there are more to be expected. Or phrased differently, none of the longer-bitted values start with the bits of shorter-bitted possible values.